# Running maven goals clean install in Intellij IDEA getting error Invalid initial heap size: -Xms=256m

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, maven-3

I'm running Maven clean install from IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.21 and it's terminated almost immediately after starting it:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\beniregev\workspace\tool-elastic-search-injector -Xms=256m -Xmx512m "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=53516:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.3.2 clean install

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms=256m
```

Here's the **m2.conf**:

```
main is org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli from plexus.core

set maven.conf default ${maven.home}/conf

[plexus.core]
load       ${maven.conf}/logging
optionally ${maven.home}/lib/ext/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/lib/*.jar
```

And here's my **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <swagger-annotations.version>1.5.20</swagger-annotations.version>
        <swagger-plugin.version>3.1.7</swagger-plugin.version>
        <springfox.swagger2.version>2.9.2</springfox.swagger2.version>
        <junit-jupiter-api.version>5.1.0</junit-jupiter-api.version>
        <mockito-core.version>2.23.4</mockito-core.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>5.3</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <android-json.version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</android-json.version>
        <lib-logging.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</lib-logging.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.beniregev.apps</groupId>
    <artifactId>search-injector</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- V10 depedencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beniregev.apps</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-api.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>${android-json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beniregev.apps</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${lib-logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.beniregev.apps.injector.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have looked all over my application and don't have anywhere where I set the JVM heap with Xms or Xmx. Also, setting Xms and Xmx should be like `-Xms256m` and `-Xmx512m` not as it's shown in the command generated by *IntelliJ*.

Where and how does *IntelliJ* generates this line??

I have the same error when trying to build other applications with `mvn clean install`.

I created a new *Spring Boot* application and used *IntelliJ* to build it with `mvn clean install` -- it was built without errors.

I cloned my project to a completely new folder `c:\beniregev\workspace\tools-elastic-search-injector`, the original folder was `c:\development\JavaProjects\IdeaProjects\tools-elastic-search-injector`.

I've checked the Settings before posting this question. Also verified I don't have `JAVA_OPTIONS` in the Environment on my machine.

I need to change `-Xms=256m` to `-Xms256m` -- where do I do that? Looks like IntelliJ has a default or value is set somewhere.

What am I missing? What else I need to check? Any other Settings/Variables that I missed?

Running `"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\mvn" clean install` produce the same error:

[image]

Comment: check your `<IDE_HOME>` , there you will find `bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions` , make changes there.

Comment: Check the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | **VM Options** field. What do you have there?

Comment: I've checked the Settings before posting this question. Also verified I don't have `JAVA_OPTIONS` in the Environment Variables on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

*I need to change -Xms=256m to -Xms256m -- where do I do that? Looks like IntelliJ has a default or value is set somewhere.*

```
Help->Edit Custom VM Options
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it wasn't `JAVA_OPTIONS` but `MAVEN_OPTS` Environment Variable that caused the problem.
[image: Environment Variables]

I removed the *equal sign* (=), restarted all IntelliJ IDEA instances and it all works now.

What gave me the idea to check it was the fact that the machine I'm working on is not mine, but the property of the company I work for now and I'm not the first to have it. I decided to assume that nobody completely delete the machine and nobody made a fresh installation.

So, I just went through the installation process of Java 8, IntelliJ IDEA, Maven, Apache Tomcat, PostgreSQL, Elasticsearch, Kibana, Logstash, Rabbit MQ, JMeter, Cucumber and all the other programs and tools I'm using and I came across that `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable. Checked it's value on my machine and WALLA - solution found.